# set xterm.vt100.faceSize from commandline

Tags: xterm, x-resources

I am searching for this solution for quite a bit.

I do not have access to `~/.Xresources`; probably it's disabled by the administrator. Hence I need to set the facesize from the terminal.

```
xterm -xrm "XTerm.VT100.faceSize 24"
```

It opens an `xterm` but with default `faceSize` 14. How can I change it from the commandline?

I know it's possible to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+rightclick and then select on of the drop-down options. But I am looking for either:

1. a permanent solution (e.g. a file in home directory)
2. or setting it from terminal when I call `xterm` (so that I can put into my aliases)

Thanks.

Comment: How did you conclude you don't have access to `.Xresources`? Remember it is a dot file and thus many file managers won't display it unless told so. And yes, you can use an alias with that. [How to create one](https://askubuntu.com/a/17538)?

Comment: You're also missing a colon: `xterm -xrm "XTerm.VT100.faceSize: 24"`

Comment: @Quasímodo by doing ls ~/.x (tab-key) , ~/.X (tab-key). The only hit was .xsession-errors. 'colon' or 'no colon' this doesn't work. Yes, I can create an alias once I get to the right option. I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: Just because a ~/.Xresources file doesn't exist in your account, it doesn't mean it's been disabled by your administrator. Just create the file yourself with a text editor of your choice.

Comment: Ok, I created a ~/.Xresources file with a single line in it: `XTerm.VT100.faceSize: 24` . Executed `xrdb -load ~/.Xresources` --> no impact. `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` --> also no impact. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use a `.` in `XTerm.VT100` (use `*`, e.g., `XTerm*VT100`).  The [*FAQ*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#my_xdefaults) might be useful.